# WordPress Theme help setting a fixed header + menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to get the header and menu below it to be fixed/sticky and always be visible but can figure out how to do both.

http://goo.gl/rBxqUm

Comment: @sdcr I know what he means. Needs a navigation bar that scrolls down with the webpage that is fixed to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery can be implemented in the theme. You adjust the number to however far down the page you want to scroll before the navigation appears. Then you style the `fixed-nav` class in the CSS to override the navigation's styles and make it fixed to the top of the page.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    var nav = $('.cap-primary-menu');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 136) {
            nav.addClass("fixed-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("fixed-nav");
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.cap-primary-menu.fixed-nav { z-index: 9999; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; }
```

**Source:**
http://www.sutanaryan.com/how-to-create-fixed-menu-when-scrolling-page-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: I added your jQuery code to my theme's jQuery file which ended with ` // Close anon function.
}( jQuery ) ); ` and I placed it below that on the next line.  Then I added your css code to the bottom of my theme's style.css but nothing happened (I also added !important at the end just in case). What did I miss?  I copied your code as-is and just pasted the at the bottom of my theme files.  Thanks for the reply btw :)

Comment: Did you include the jQuery with your Theme?

Comment: [Solved] Thanks so much! My problem was with styling the top area because .cap-primary-menu only contains the menu and not the logo or the phone+caption on the top right.  The logo+phone+caption were on the theme's style sheet in .cap-menu-below so I set this to top:0; and then I set .cap-primary-menu to top:50px; so that the menu is below the header (logo container) and they are both fixed.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to have helped